# Error with function used to create correlation matrix needed for heatmap?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, matrix, heatmap

I am trying to create a function that fills in an empty data frame "dummy" with the correlations between various columns of data in a data frame called "master".

This is my function:

```
master <- read.table("~/Desktop/Heatmap_Project/master.txt", header = T, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = F)

vector_a <- names(master)[2:4] 
vector_b <- names(master)[11:18]
# Such that, you compare every column in vector_a with every column in vector_b 


heatmap_prep <- function(dataframe, vector_a,vector_b){
    dummy <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol=length(vector_a), nrow=length(vector_b)))
    for (i in 1:length(vector_a)){
                first_value <- dataframe[[ vector_a[i]  ]]
                # print(first_value)
            for(j in 1:length(vector_b)){
                    second_value <- dataframe[[ vector_b[j] ]]
                    # print(second_value)
                    result <- cor(first_value, second_value)
                    dummy [i,j] <- result
            }
        }
        return(as.matrix(dummy))
    }

heatmap_data_matrix1 <- heatmap_prep(master,vector_a, vector_b)
```

It works until "return", however when I run the function "heatmap_prep" it returns a bunch of NAs. I want it to fill out the whole matrix with all the correlations.

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Please don't use `read.table` in your example.  It's useless to everyone else. Instead provide some actual dummy data that is reproducible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the shape of `dummy` wrong - columns and rows are reversed for how you assign them in `dummy [i,j] <- result`

This should work if you change to

```
  dummy <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow=length(vector_a), ncol=length(vector_b)))
```